# Register using nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

on `server.js` i have this code to register new user on my db

```
server.post("http://localhost:5555/signup", (req, res) => {
    const { lname,fname,username, email, password } = req.body;
    
    // Check if a user with the same email or username already exists
    User.findOne({ $or: [ { email: email }, { username: username } ] })
      .then(existingUser => {
        if (existingUser) {
          // User with the same email or username already exists
          res.status(409).json({ error: "User already exists, please login" });
        } else {
          // Create a new user
          const newUser = new User({ fname,lname,username, email, password });
          newUser
            .save()
            .then((User) => {
              console.log(user);
              res.status(200).json(user);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.error(err);
              res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error" });
            });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error" });
      });
});
```

On console user created but not stored on my mongodb

Comment: Code is fine. May be you are inserting in different DB & looking into different DB.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
const server = express.Router();

server.post("/http://localhost:5555/signup", (req, res) => {
const { lname,fname,username, email, password } = req.body;

// Check if a user with the same email or username already exists
schema.findOne({ $or: [ { email: email }, { username: username } ] })
  .then(existingUser => {
    if (existingUser) {
      // User with the same email or username already exists
      res.status(409).json({ error: "User already exists, please login" });
    } else {
      // Create a new user
      const newUser = new schema({ fname,lname,username, email, password });
      newUser
        .save()
        .then((User) => {
          console.log(User);
          res.status(200).json(User);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
          res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error" });
        });
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error" });
  });
 });
```

Your code is proper make sure you require route as a name **server**

```
.then((User) => {
      console.log(User);
      res.status(200).json(User);
    })
```

You define capital user in **.then((User))** and you access **console.log(user)** in small user please you add **console.log(User)** and check your data add properly